# Using virt-install and setting vnc port to listen on ipv6

Tags: ssh, ipv6, portforwarding, kvm, vnc

I'm running into an issue when I try to vnc into a new VM created with virt-install. When specifying vnc with virt-install using this:

```
--vnc \
--vncport=5905 \
--noautoconsole
```

The VM is created and 5905 is listening, but only on ipv4 as shown here:

```
# netstat -l | grep 5905
tcp        0      0 localhost:5905          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The problem is when I try to SSH tunnel using "ssh -v -L 5905:localhost:5905 myhost", I get a connection refused error because the vnc port is trying to forward from the hosts ipv6 local loopback interface and the vnc port is not listening on it:

```
debug1: Connection to port 5905 forwarding to localhost port 5905 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5905 for localhost port 5905, connect from ::1 port 57890 to ::1 port 5905, nchannels 4
```

I could solve this also by connecting vnc to the hosts ipv4 local loopback, but I'm not sure how to do that. Ideally I would like to have vnc listen on both ipv4 and ipv6.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the VM to listen on ipv6 by editing the xml to include this in the graphics parameter:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='5905' autoport='no' listen='localhost'>
  <listen type='address' address='localhost'/>
</graphics>
```

You can specify this in the virt-install command by using this:

```
--graphics vnc,listen=localhost,port=5905 \
```

If you ask me, virt-install should default to localhost instead of it's ipv4 local loopback :/